# Is there any way to output the result of a column of each row to show a different value in OracleDB using PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a Select Statement that has a column which is a code value. For e.g. instead of Java its JV, and instead of Python its PY. However, instead of outputting the coded value, I would like to display them as Java or Python i.e. their full description. Is there a way to do this with PL/SQL?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `case` expression

```
select
   case 
     when myColumn = 'JV' then 'Java'
     when myColumn = 'PY' then 'Python'
   end as myColumn
from yourTable
```

In `oracle` you can use `decode` as well.

```
 decode(col, 'JV', 'Java',
             'PY', 'Python'
             'No Match'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. What if I have other columns to output too, where do I write this code in?

Comment: @loveprogramming you can add columns like `select col1, col2, col3 from myTable`. or if you need to have case statement then add other `case` statement.

Comment: Note that there is no need to repeat the "myColumn = " portion of the comparison on each condition. You can do that if there is a completely different calculation for each condition, but when doing a simple decode you can just say

"CASE myColumn WHEN 'JV' THEN 'Java' ..."

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Oracle, I would recommend using the `DECODE` function:

```
SELECT
    col,
    DECODE(col, 'JV', 'Java',
                'PY', 'Python',
                'Not found') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the "DECODE" function, or a "CASE" construct, as follows:

```
select DECODE(my_column,
              'JV','Java',
              'PY','Python',
              'no_match_found') my_column_alias 
from my_table;

select
   case my_column 
      when 'JV' then 'Java'
      when 'PY' then 'Python'
      else 'no_match_found'
   end my_column_alias
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are several ways of hard coding the for the sample data given none are the proper method for more than a very limited set. The proper method is to create a lookup table. In this case contains the code and corresponding name.  Yes, it is quite overkill for 2 languages, but how about the [TIOBE Index](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) or the 700 listed in Wikipedia, or the estimated approximately 9000 claimed in the HOPL list.  See [here](https://careerkarma.com/blog/how-many-coding-languages-are-there/) and additional links more.  
  
Moreover it is a **standard technique** to OP underlying question: Is there a way to give detail about a given code value.
It is easily extended (just add row to a table) and  applicable across virtually all domains (abet with slight modifications).

```
-- create language lookup
create table language_lookup(
       code        varchar2(8)
     , name        varchar2(200)
     , description varchar2(4000)
     , constraint  language_lookup_pk
                   primary key (code)
     ); 

insert into language_lookup(code, name)
  select 'JV','Java'      from dual union all
  select 'PY','Python'    from dual ;


-- your table 
create table your_table ( id        integer
                        , lang_code varchar2(8)
                          --... 
                        , constraint your_table_pk 
                                     primary key (id)
                        , constraint your_table_2_language_lookup_fk
                                     foreign key (lang_code) 
                                     references language_lookup(code)
                        ) ;
insert into your_table (id, lang_code)
  select 1,'JV'  from dual union all 
  select 2,'PY'  from dual;

select yt.lang_code, ll.name 
   from your_table      yt
   join language_lookup ll 
     on ll.code = yt.lang_code
  where yt.lang_code in ('JV','PY')
; 

-- now modify to include plsql
insert into language_lookup(code, name)
  values ( 'PLSQL', 'Oracle''s Programming Language extension for SQL');
insert into your_table (id,lang_code)
  values (3,'PLSQL');

select yt.lang_code, ll.name 
   from your_table      yt
   join language_lookup ll 
     on ll.code = yt.lang_code
;
```

Try that with your hard coded values. Then add 30 - 40 more ...